# SPRING Lookup failed for 'jdbc/ww2b/DataSource' in SerialContext

Tags: spring, datasource, glassfish-3, jndi, server-configuration

```
[#|2014-04-01T15:19:03.824+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=76;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|15:19:03.822 [admin-thread-pool-4848(5)] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryUiDao': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/web/WEB-INF/lib/core-2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/spring/db-env.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/web/WEB-INF/lib/core-2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/spring/db-env.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jdbc/ww2b/DataSource' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/ww2b/DataSource' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/jdbc/ww2b/DataSource} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ww2b]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
```

what is wrong. When I build a project everything works but when I try to deploy to glassfish3 I get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Spring application configuration is right it seems that the JNDI resource `java:comp/env/jdbc/ww2b/DataSource` is not correctly configured on the server.

You should configure JNDI resource on GlassFish as described in the [Administrator Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4335/ablih/index.html#6nfqc3qgq).

Comment: Thank you, I will configure it now